# Is there a NOT operator in calabash query syntax?

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

The title pretty well covers my question.  How can I (for instance) obtain all the TextView elements whose IDs do NOT CONTAIN "some_prefix"?  I can obtain all TextView elements and iterate over them, kicking out the ones I don't like (and I probably will), but I'd rather have a clear query which does that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inefficient, but you can do:

```
query("android.widget.TextView") -
    query("android.widget.TextView {id CONTAINS[c] 'some_prefix'}")
```

The first `query` gets the set of all TextViews, then excludes those that contain 'some_prefix' as returned in the second `query`.